# getFragmentManager().popbackstack() causing nullpointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, back-stack

I am developing an android app with lots of fragments in it. But I am facing problems in switching between them.

Lets say I have a Fragment A now I want to go to Fragment B, for this I am doing like this--

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager
                            .beginTransaction();
                    Fragment fragment = new Fragment_B();                   
                    transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
```

I reach Fragment B successfully. Now I have to go to Fragment C from here, for this again I am doing the same thing.

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager
                                .beginTransaction();
                        Fragment fragment = new Fragment_C();                   
                        transaction.add(R.id.frameLayot, fragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
```

I do this successfully also. Now I have to revert back to Fragment B, for this I do -

```
getFragmentManager.popbackstack();
```

This brings me back to Fragment B. But when I do the same to go to Fragment A now, it causes NullpointerException.

What I am doing wrong here. Why does this run perfectly for the first time but fails at the second time? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to check first there are fragment available in backstack or not. follow my below code:

```
if(manager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
    manager.popBackStack();
    manager.beginTransaction().commit();
}
```

Thats it...

and yes you do not add fragment a to backstack initally so crosscheck that..

Comment: My Fragment Activity launches (adds) a PagerFragment firstup (i.e in its onCreate). This Pager Fragment has 3 fragments in it. Fragment A is the first of these three. Fragment B and C are out of this pagerfragment and are completely different.

Comment: ok then when your pager activity add Fragment A same like Fragment B you have to write transaction.addToBackStack(null); thats it...

Answer (score 2):

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
 }
```